# asio::use_future and event loop

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-asio

Im browsing asio feature **use_future**, reading the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/asio/impl/use_future.hpp).

But cannot figure out how it works. Say, if i call

```
auto fut = async_write(sock, buffer, use_future)
```

`fut` becomes `std::future` (according to source code). Now, if i call `fut.get()` i should able to wait async operation complete and get return value. In the `use_future.hpp` file i see standard for asio `async_result` handler resolution and so on..

But if i block on `future::get()` call, how the IO loop continue to work so operation can complete? Does it create a system thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Asio [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) mentions that for single-threaded applications, one may observe poor responsiveness if handlers take a long time to complete.  In this case, if only one thread is processing the `io_service`, then one would observe a deadlock.

When [`boost::asio::use_future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/use_future.html) is used, the initiating operation will:

- initiate the underlying operation with a completion handler that will set the value or error on a `std::promise`
- return to the caller a `std::future` associated with the `std::promise`.

If a single thread is processing the I/O service, and it blocks on `future::get()`, then the completion handler that would set the `std::promise` will never be invoked.  It is the application's responsibility to prevent this from occurring.  The [official futures example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp) accomplishes this by creating an additional thread that is dedicated to processing the I/O service and waits on `std::future` from within a thread that is not processing the I/O service.

```cpp
// We run the io_service off in its own thread so that it operates
// completely asynchronously with respect to the rest of the program.
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
std::thread thread([&io_service](){ io_service.run(); });

std::future<std::size_t> send_length =
  socket.async_send_to(..., boost::asio::use_future);

// Do other things here while the send completes.

send_length.get(); // Blocks until the send is complete. Throws any errors.
```

Comment: This makes more sense. But what if `use_future` is used inside of the handlers, called by `io_service::run` ? This will be deadlock again. Seems this feature is not so safe as i seems =(

Comment: @PSIAlt Calling functions that may indefinitely block from within handlers is rarely safe.  When I use `use_future`, I only use it from threads that are not processing the I/O service, and all async operations those threads initiate use `use_future`.   This approach has no user handlers in which blocking calls can be made.

Comment: but this also means you should use thread per connection to make this pattern work. I'll better stick with yield_context instead, it seems more extendable.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it create a system thread?

No. You're <strike>supposed</strike> free to decide on which thread(s) to run `io_service::run`

Comment: The [Platform-Specific Implementation Notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) lists all internal threads.  This [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d85347255e8d84dd) shows that even if the OS operation completes, if the `io_service` does not get processed, then the promise never gets fulfilled.

Comment: So the question is: if i have only 1 thread and its blocking in `future::get` call, where `io_service::run` is processed in order to call `promise_handler` ?